# Update Market Application to Google Play Market Application

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have the problem with latest update which re-brands "Market" app 
to "Google Play Market" app.

At one moment "Market" icon disappeared from both home screen and applications. 
I was seeking for the solution to that, found some (weird at the time) "Play Market" update installed 
and have uninstalled it. This brought back "Market" application.

Later I have seen that this was a silent patch which I should not uninstall!

Problem is, that, when I start "Market" app it ONLY displays following page in browser:
https://play.google.com/about/android-developer-policies.html

I am stuck here with this page, and the app is not updating again to "Play Market"

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data for the Market? `Settings->Applications->Market->Clear Data button`

Comment: Yes, tried that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try clearing the data for the Market and rebooting the phone.  Then log in to the Market, wait a minute, then back out and continue using your phone with the internet connection active.  Hopefully the Market should update itself within a few minutes.

Or, you can just download and install the .apk.  I rely on Android Police for the latest version; they've posted 3.9.16 [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/11/download-latest-google-play-store-3-9-16-with-new-ability-to-remove-apps-from-the-all-apps-list/).

Comment: Thank you very much.
Problem was a big Android nonsense.
I was connected to internet via USB pass-through. 
Once I turned on WiFi option (with no internet) it worked and updated instantly!

Cannot believe this!

Comment: Thank you, it also worked for me, the whole stuff with clearing the Market data and restarting the phone and leaving the Market app in peace for a few minutes was necessary.