# How to remove apps from "all downloaded" in Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

In the new Android Market/Play Store (3.5.15) they have now got a list of "all downloaded" apps.

I have had an android phone for a good 2/3 years now and the list is huge, plus sightly more questionable apps which should have been lost in the ether of the internet have now been dredged back up to haunt me.

Can I remove apps from here?

Thanks

Comment: lol! absolutely! :p glad to know I'm not the only one!

Comment: Just to clarify: This is about the Android app, not the Play Store website, correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<del>No, it's not possible. The android market is plagued with issues like this one.</del>

As of version 3.9.16 you can finally now remove applications from the "all" tab in the my apps list. You can even select several apps at once by long pressing one, then selecting the others.
These apps are removed from the Website too.

<sup>Source: [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/11/download-latest-google-play-store-3-9-16-with-new-ability-to-remove-apps-from-the-all-apps-list/)</sup>

Comment: At least on my Tablet (running Android 4.1.1, Play Store 3.10.10) it works going to "My Apps", select "All Apps", and hit the delete-symbol next to the unwanted. It pops up a confirmation, and if I approve it disappears from both, the Playstore app and the website. Only annoying thing is: No multi-select, and after each delete it jumps back right to the top of the list...

Comment: Have to correct myself to the better: Of course Richard is right with the "Long Press"! This way one can even live with the jump-to-start. Big thumbs-up for this, just did a huge clean-up :)

Comment: @Izzy looks like they changed the behavior since I wrote this. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: I am on kitkat (Nexus 5), when I long hold an app under "All" tab, and release it, it opens uninstall page corresponding app. I do not see any option to multiselect

Comment: @TechJerk If it opens the uninstall screen, that means the app is still installed. The question is about removing apps that are no longer installed on your phone.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik  On Android 4.4.4 I was able to select multiple apps but there is no remove button (X) to remove all the apps at once

Answer (score 11):

This was left as an edit to another post by an anonymous user, but should be its own answer.

---

Go to the Google Play app on your mobile phone and go to Menu -> My Apps, then swipe across to All Apps. Delete the app from there using the symbol button on the right, and the app will also delete from the online Play Store list.

In order to delete several applications at a time, long-press an application until a blue top bar appears; then short-press some other applications, and you will be able to delete all selected applications by pressing the deletion symbol in the upper-right corner, in the blue bar. This is especially practical because you jump to the top of the list after deleting an application, and the list is only sorted by date of first installation—at least at this moment.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: THAT'S new to me!  Extremely unobvious though... it took me a bit before I saw the little outline of a circle with a line next to the app name on the right. I would have thought a trash can (like on https://play.google.com/apps) would be more intuitive - quite aside from making it nearly invisible!  Light grey on white... sheesh!

Comment: The question is, **how** do I delete it? Holding down the item doesn't seem to yield any context menu of sorts.

Comment: @ShedoSurashu Please see Logos' comment and the screenshot I added.  (This is on the 3.9.16 Play Store.)  I'm not quite sure why I can't do it with SuperSU however.

Comment: I'm using 3.5.19, how do I update it?

Comment: @ShedoSurashu See http://android.stackexchange.com/a/20386/1465

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to remove multiple entries from the All list of apps with the new version of Google Play.

Long press on the first app to remove and a header bar will appear with a check mark and a delete symbol. Tap all the apps you want to remove and then tap the delete symbol.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working on mine. (Droid 3, Android 2.3.4, Play Store App version 3.9.16) Perhaps this is ICS+?

Comment: Works a treat on my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @DylanYaga What do you get when you long press an entry in the list?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik It sits there, doing nothing, mocking me... :(

Comment: Fair Warning: I think it only let's you do this with FREE apps. Once you add an app that is paid the delete symbols goes away in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more up to date description from [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521768?hl=en&ref_topic=3364672):

> If you want to remove an app from showing on My Apps, touch the "X" to
>   remove apps that you don't want displayed on the All category.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019-12-07 on Android 9 with playstore 17.8.14, one has to go to "play store -> my apps & games -> library -> click on the X symbol next to the application you wish to remove.

[image]