# Is there a way to clear your Google Play App history? (Not the search history)

Tags: applications, google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/how-to-remove-apps-from-all-downloaded-in-play-store)

I'm looking to see if there is a way to clear the actual history of installed apps in Google Play, as opposed to the history of searches (which one can do right from the app).

It'd be nice to be able to wipe out the old apps that I tried months ago and uninstalled. The sorting of the "All" apps list is actually pretty good, in that such apps tend to be at the very bottom; but if I go on a tangent trying a dozen different similar apps until I decide on one, I'll have those in my list for a bit.

And, sure... there are a few apps in that list I installed then removed that might generate a blush or two if someone else saw it.

I wouldn't expect to be able to remove apps that I have installed on any of my devices (nor would I want to, anyway)... just apps that I installed previously but do not have any longer.

Comment: Certainly doesn't appear to be any way.

Comment: @eldarerathis Yup; definitely a dupe!  Sucks about the answer.

Comment: I would delete, but the stack exchange twitter bot tweeted this!

Comment: I think this is a good title to keep around anyway since the other one doesn't use the word "history" anywhere (and it's probably a search term that a lot of people will use).

Comment: @eldarerathis Excellent point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is impossible the only way is changing of account. That way the apps you have deleted or uninstalled will not appear because is not the same account.

EDIT:

It is now possible

Go to apps then choose all

From the list hold the app you wish to delete, remove will appear in top right corner, tap remove and your done