# How do I remove an app from the "My Android Apps" page?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/how-to-remove-apps-from-all-downloaded-in-play-store)

I have a bunch of apps that I tried before then uninstalled. Now they're showing up on https://play.google.com/apps but I don't think I'll be installing them any more in the future. How do I remove them from there?

Comment: There is [a related question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/how-to-remove-apps-from-all-downloaded-in-new-play-store-3-5-15) specifically related to the Play Store mobile app as well.

Comment: Please see [How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/16575). [Richard's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/20794/16575) there explains how this can be done using the playstore app. Items removed that way also disappear from the corresponding web page (I just verified this).