# Removing Apps from "Other apps in my library" in Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove an app from the “My Android Apps” page?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/how-do-i-remove-an-app-from-the-my-android-apps-page)

Is it possible to remove some apps from appearing in "Other apps in my library" in "My Apps" in Google Play when logged in from my Google Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is up as a 'Known Issue' on the Google website.

See: http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs&ki_topic=1319135

Under 'Google Play Website'

Sorry.

Comment: Not quite true anymore, see [How to remove apps from “all downloaded” in Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/16575) :) So it *is* possible *now* (but right, it wasn't possible for a long time, and probably not at the time you gave your answer).