# Is it possible to batch remove apps in the Web Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation

**This question has been [asked in the past](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20732/how-to-remove-apps-from-all-downloaded-in-play-store) (together with several duplicated pointing to it) but the answer is not relevant anymore (as of March 2015).** The current version is 5.3.6 while the solutions are for 3.9.16 and not forward compatible.

I have lots of apps visible in the Web Google Play (under `My Apps -> All Apps`) and I would like to get rid of them (among others so that new devices do not try to install them).
They are not visible on my phone (neither in the 'Installed' nor in 'All' tab).

Is there a way to do that? (when clicking on the app on the web I just see an 'Installed' status (which is not correct, it is not installed anymore, anywhere) without the possibility of changing it).

The only idea I have is to force a synchronization between my device and the web Google play (via Titanium Backup for instance), clean up on the device and hope that the changes will be reflected back in Web Google Play.