# Google Play says "You don't have any devices"

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, google-account, samsung-galaxy-ace

I tried factory resetting so I need to enter my Google account again to my device however it's been more than an hour now and Google Play still says "You don't have any devices". Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Contact Google...

Comment: Are you getting this on the web store or on the device?  It doesn't make sense that it would happen on the device.  Have you tried [upgrading Google Play](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/20386/1465)?

Comment: @MatthewRead The device works fine. The web store doesn't.

Comment: @AndroidQuesito "Contact Google" is notoriously hard though...

Answer (score 3):

Try following (Worked in my case)

1. Remove Google account from settings
2. Clear data of play-store and Google services framework
3. Restart phone Now access play store again.

Comment: I know this works but in my case this time it didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me. Without removing the google account it din't work.

Comment: Worked for me by doing just the first half of step 2, and then downloading any app (which may or may not be necessary). Also see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/55590/204215.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install some apps. directly on device using Google Play, then you will find your device after sometime, happened to me many a times.